# How can I determine user / group when running an application?

Tags: file, ubuntu, permissions, nextcloud

I'm running nextCloud on my own Virtual Private Server with Ubuntu 16 + Plesk. I have a weird behavior which I suspect is related to files access rights:
- Configured an external storage (secondary HDD, mounted in /media as /diskext) as the "shared company repository". All users should have access to this repository.
- Verified that the shared NC folder has the proper rights by chown ncadmin:psacln, where pascln is Plesk default execution group.
- When accessing nextCloud from my desktop, I have access to the shared repository.
- Other colleagues with the same privileges have no access!

Therefore I'd like to determine what are the user/group used by nextCloud when trying to access the repository as user1, user2 or user15. I have a root SSH access to the server, so can run command line...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Nextcloud uses the user under which the PHP process runs to access the filesystem.
E.g. when you are using Apache and mod_php on ubuntu this is `www-data`.

To check which user this is on your system create the file `phpinfo.php` in `/var/www/html` with the following contents:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Then go to the `http://<ip-address-here>/phpinfo.php` url, you will find the user under `Environment`.

Then you can change the user of the disk by running `chown -R user:psacln`.

Make sure to remove the `phpinfo.php` file since this may contain some sensitive values.